# Having trouble while Installing a Nuget package(WIndows.winMD)

Tags: c#

Getting error while trying to install a Nuget Package

I'm trying to install a pakage and get the following error:
NuGet\Install-Package Microsoft.Windows.WinMD -Version 1.0.210629.2'

NuGet\Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.Windows.WinMD 1.0.210629.2'. You
are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2',
but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible
with that framework.

Please help

Comment: The error says it all - the package has not assembly reference for .NETFramework 4.7.2. Try installing it on a project that is on another framework.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that you want to write a .net wrapper over a C++?
If so, this is nuget package does not contain dll files. Most likely you need to build the C++ library first and add build result as content in your project.

Answer (score 0):

This nuget package framework is tagged with `native`.

[nuget: Microsoft.Windows.WinMD - Frameworks](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.WinMD#supportedframeworks-body-tab)

The `native` framework tag is for C++ projects.

[DevBlogs: Support for Native Projects](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/native-support/)

Conclusion: This package can not be consumed or used by any C# project.

However, in the [nuget used-by tab](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.WinMD#usedby-body-tab) of that package is a reference to a C++ github project that uses this package and is described as

> C# language projection for the Windows Runtime

You may have a look at that.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1069 The type name 'DeviceWatcher' could not be found in the namespace 'Windows.Devices.Enumeration'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime' Consider adding a reference to that assembly. ConsoleApp1 C:\Work\C#\workspace\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs 22 Active

Comment: My end goal is to create an desktop app that talks to STM 32 BLUE NRG Bluetooth module. Form everything I read online I have to use the Windows.Devices.Enumeration to start scanning the device information. To do the above I have to use the windows.winMD. I have added it form C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.22000.0\Facade path. I dont understand why the windoes version is coming up like that. I'm new to C#. Can you explain this?

Comment: This is for sure a new question and so you should start a new question. My answer is related to the question you originally asked. Not more, not less. This is the rule here on SO: One question and hopefully in the end One (accepted) answer - because it is a Q&A (Question and Answer) site.